# raspberrypi package not found

Tags: raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running catkin build in my catkin_ws  workspace I get the following error:
Note added: I do not have a standard /op/ros/kinetic directory...just the catkin workspaces.

```
pi@dex: catkin build
Starting  >>> ropigo                                                           
_______________________________________________________________________________
Errors     << ropigo:make /home/pi/catkin_ws/logs/ropigo/build.make.004.log    
/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/ropigo/src/ropigo.cpp:3:33: fatal error: geometry_msgs/Twist.h: No such file or directory
 #include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
                                 ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ropigo_node.dir/src/ropigo.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ropigo_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

cd /home/pi/catkin_ws/build/ropigo; catkin build --get-env ropigo | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/make --jobserver-fds=6,7 -j; cd -
...............................................................................
Failed     << ropigo:make                         [ Exited with code 2 ]       
Failed    <<< ropigo                              [ 42.4 seconds ]             
[build] Summary: 16 of 17 packages succeeded.                                  
[build]   Ignored:   None.                                                     
[build]   Warnings:  None.                                                     
[build]   Abandoned: None.                                                     
[build]   Failed:    1 packages failed.                                        
[build] Runtime: 3 minutes and 57.8 seconds total.
```

If I look for Twish.h it is found as follows. The ros_catkin_ws is my primary workspace where I loaded ros desktop install

```
pi@dex:~ $ sudo find . / -name Twist.h
/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel/.private/geometry_msgs/include/geometry_msgs/Twist.h
/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel/include/geometry_msgs/Twist.h
```

In .bashrc file I have

```
source ~/ros_catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

Finally if I echo ROS_PACKAGE_PATH ,/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/common_msgs/geometry_msgs:/ is in the path.

Can someone give me a hand here. Why is it not finding the include file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260915/raspberrypi-package-not-found/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2017-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

stopped using this method for installing ros on the pi

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2017-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0